# Filter Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

So after much experimentation I have found that the syntax I needed to filter products based on their specs is as follows

```
{

"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "productSpecification",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "productSpecification.name": "Brand"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "productSpecification.value": [
                                            "Brand1"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "productSpecification",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "productSpecification.name": "Guarantee"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "productSpecification.value": [
                                            "3 years"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I'm now experimenting with creating a QueryContainer function to build this based on the selected name/values, If anyone can give me a point in the right direction on this that would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `post_filter`? This is useful when returning both hits from a search request **and** aggregations, but only want to supply a set of filters to the search hits (the use case here is faceted search e.g. show results with facets to the side). If you don't need to do this, then just need the `bool` inside of `query`

Comment: I have a solution for this will post soon

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am now building a query from nest that works but is a bit messier than the DSL query above (not sure if someone can spot what Im doing below that makes it have some unnecessary bool filters

Here is my nest syntax

```
.PostFilter(pf => FilterTest(elasticParams,pf))

private static QueryContainer FilterTest(ElasticParams elasticParams, QueryContainerDescriptor<Product>q) => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Filter(fi => FilterSelected(elasticParams, fi)));

private static QueryContainer FilterSelected2(ElasticParams elasticParams, QueryContainerDescriptor<Product> q) =>
        elasticParams.Filters.Aggregate(new QueryContainer(), (c, s) => c && +q.Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
            .Query(qq => qq
                .Bool(bo => bo
                    .Filter(fi => fi
                        .Term(tt => tt
                            .Field(a => a.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                            .Value(s.name)) && fi
                        .Terms(ttt => ttt
                            .Field(fff => fff.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))
                            .Terms(s.Values))

                )))));
```

As mentioned before this is filters as I would want however it DSL that it outputs is rather fugly as can be seen below

```
{

"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [{
            "bool": {
                "filter": [{
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [{
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [{
                                            "term": {
                                                "productSpecification.name": {
                                                    "value": "Brand"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "productSpecification.value": ["Brand1", "Brand2"]
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "productSpecification"
                    }
                }, {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [{
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [{
                                            "term": {
                                                "productSpecification.name": {
                                                    "value": "Guarantee"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "productSpecification.value": ["3 years"]
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "productSpecification"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think this needs to be a `post_filter`, as this does not appear to be returning both query and aggregations results for the purpose of faceting. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html for more details. Also, Executing the query in a `bool` query `filter` clause is probably what you want. Also, query is larger because `.Terms()` query is `&&`ed with the `.Term()` query. I think what you want here instead of `&& fi` is `, fi => fi`, as the .Filter()` takes a `params Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>[] queries`